# Inter-satellite linking for satellite constellations?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite, radio-communication

All the existent satellite constellations and the proposed ones talk about **inter-plane** communications as a very challenging issue due to:

- High relative velocities between satellites
- Tracking control problems as antennas must slew around
- Doppler shift

I wonder why a different approach is not considered. Is it possible for a hybrid topology: combining a ring topology with a star topology?
In other words, satellites from one plane can communicate among themselves (ring), and if they want to "talk" to a satellite in another plane, they could use a higher orbit satellite (something as a **hub**) and do the whole routing.

What are the pros and cons fo this approach against typical inter-planar communication?

Comment: The TDRSS system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System seems relevant...

Comment: Also the hosted EDRS laser communications payload on a Eutelsat, http://spaceflight101.com/proton-eutelsat-9b/eutelsat-9b-spacecraft-overview/

Comment: It's just expensive no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good solution to a sticky problem, pointing accuracy is a real pain in the butt on Earth (when you're stationary) let alone when in orbit (not quite so stationary).

The Cons...

> 1. ***MONEY***  - this is a big one. It's not cheap to get a satellite to orbit. Depending on your requirements, might be as cheap as a
>      couple million dollars or as expensive as a couple hundred
>      million dollars. Whichever number you think is feasible, double it.
>      Now double it again. 1 satellite means the Earth might be between your
>      constellation and your communication hub; 2 could probably do the job
>      though, but what if something does wrong.. heck let's stick a couple
>      of redundancies in orbit as well... which brings me to...
> 2. To solve the problem of a constellation you've made a constellation - seriously.. try selling this to the guys who count the money. All these extra satellites actually increase all sorts of risks (eg. Space
>      debris collision, launch failure, etc.).
> 3. Does this really fix the issue? A satellite in a high orbit does move slower, and if it's further from the final inter-plane satellite
>      then the *relative angular change* would be lower. However, the
>      question of what's the ideal orbit soon brings up other problems like
>      communication power requirements (further = bad).

The Pros...

> 1. The chosen one - the hub satellite (or satellites) could be fitted
>      with better momentum wheels and communication systems so they can
>      easily target the out of plane satellites. This hardware would likely
>      be heavy and expensive  (my phone autocorrected to expansive and it
>      could be that too). You can't afford to outfit your 57 constellation
>      satellites with this kind of gear, who are you Tony Stark!
> 2. Duel
>      purpose - or triple, quadruple etc.. This hub satellite system could
>      be used by everyone (for a small fee I'm sure). That means less stuff
>      in orbit, better standardization of satellite hardware and more cash
>      in your pocket!
> 3. Redundant redundancies - having satellites in more
>      than one plane helps mitigate the possibility that you'll lose
>      everything in orbit when I test my anti-satellite weapons. No
>      offensive intended.. I picked your constellations orbit by chance.. no
>      it has nothing to do with my competing communications constellation.
>      When something collides or explodes in orbit it could be truly
>      catastrophic for that orbital region.. and I'm talking for hundreds,
>      thousands or millions of years (increases exponentially with
>      altitude).

So that's a few Pros and Cons. Certainly not an exhaustive list. If I ever figure out how to include hyperlinks on the mobile version of SE I'll pepper this with appropriate websites.

Comment: Could someone please format this for me... list does no equal code apparently!

Comment: There's another drawback: the high-altitude satellites add lots of latency to the link. That's rather annoying for voice comms.

Comment: Oh how appropriate it is that I only noticed your comment 13 hours after you posted! Very true!

Comment: Thanks for the shared view! I agree with most of the points you have mentioned. I hope that the last case scenario is not a a common practice nowadays though!

After further thoughts about this, I would also add the Con of the added complexity to the overall system. Two different satellites architectures to be designed and especially, different launchers requirements for them as well.

Comment: @B.N if you're interested in the last scenario (and it really could happen without any anti-satellite weapons) have a look into Kessler Syndrome (just Google it). I didn't even think of complexity, good catch!